# Word for loving an idea but not the reality

Tags: single-word-requests

Is there a word for being in love with an idea but not liking the reality? Or the disparity between how you think something will be and how it actually is?

The best that I could do was "romanticisation".

An example might be: "In spite of her ____ of the job, she didn't really enjoy it at all."

Comment: So, why is *romanticization* not a good fit? In order to find the word you're looking for, we need to know what kind of qualities *romanticization* has that you're not looking for.

Comment: Expectations???

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You may use ***[idealization:](https://www.collinsdictionary.com/dictionary/english/idealization)***

> a conception of something that dwells on its advantages and ignores its deficiencies.

(Collins Dictionary)

> Despite her idealization of the job, she didn’t really enjoy it at all.

Answer (score 0):

Id say for a characterization you could use dilemma or quandary.

It must be woman in this scenario, I feel ambiguous fits too

Comment: Hi Samantha, welcome to the site!  I don't think your suggestion really answers the question, as it does not fit into the blank of the example sentence.  (I do see how it relates to the situation overall, but the question is looking for word fitting a specific aspect of the situation as demonstrated in the example.)